# Incorrect signature even though I'm correctly casting the right objects?

Tags: apex, trigger, class

For some reason, my code won't compile and I'm not entirely sure why.

The method accepts the following arguments

```
public static void doSomething(Map<Id, Order> oldMap, List<Order> orderList) {}
```

And I'm providing the following arguments from my trigger handler as such:

```
public void beforeUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) {
    List<Order> orderList = (List<Order>) newItems.values();
    ClassName.doSomething(oldItems, orderList);
}
```

Which gives me the error

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void doSomething(Map<Id,SObject>, List<Order>) from the type ClassName
```

However, using `Trigger.oldMap` and `Trigger.new` works fine and compiles as expected:

```
ClassName.doSomething(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.New);
```

`Trigger.new` is identical to `List<Order> orderList = (List<Order>) newItems.values();`

and `Trigger.oldMap` is identical to `Map<Id, SObject> oldItems`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you please try your arguments be like **public void beforeUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) {...}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to pass an instance of `Map<Id, sObject>` where it expects it to be of type `Map<Id,Order>` i.e. it expects the concrete type.

So, like you are typecasting `List<sObject>` to `List<Order>`, you will also have to typecast `Map<Id,sObject>` to `Map<Id,Order>`.

Although this typecasting is not as straight forward but it is doable using [`Map`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) methods like below

```
Map<Id, Order> mapOrders = new Map<Id, Order>((List<Order>)oldItems.values());
```

So, here a `Map<Id,sObject>` is typecast ed to `Map<Id,Order>` using below steps in single line

1. Get values from `oldMap` using `values()` method of `Map` which will return `List<sObject>`
2. Typecast it to `List<Order>`
3. And then use `Map<ID,sObject>(recordList)` constructor of map which takes `List<Order>` to construct `Map<Id,Order>`

So your code should look like this

```
public void beforeUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) {
    List<Order> orderList = (List<Order>) newItems.values();
    Map<Id, Order> mapOrders = new Map<Id, Order>((List<Order>)oldItems.values());
    ClassName.doSomething(mapOrders, orderList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I just find it weird that I didn't need to type cast when using `Trigger.oldMap` and `Trigger.new` - but with these I do?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are passing in first parameter a `Map<Id, Order>` and it excepts a `Map<Id, SObject>`
`Map<Id, Order>` cannot be casted in implicit way from `Map<Id, SObject>`
These types are not in same hierarchy, so `Map<Id, Order>` is not extending `Map<Id, SObject>` like its for eg. pair `SObject` -> `Account`

`Trigger.oldMap` compiles because types (proveded and excepted) are the same. To make it work I would suggest to make method parameters more specific (use `Order` instead of `SObject`).

Comment: So how should I cast it from `Map<Id, SObject>` to `Map<Id, Order>`?
Because just looking at the logs, isn't `Trigger.oldMap` dynamically cast from `Map<Id, SObject>` to `Map<Id, Order>`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, when you cast it before passing to function it should start compiling properly

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: Cast to proper type before passing Map to a fucntion, or change signature of funtcion that the types would correct after.